# write a python func. that asks users to enter names of people and their ages that it will put into a empty dictionary and returns it

Tags: python-3.x

so below is my attempt please help

```
emptydic = {} # an empty dict. 
name = input('Enter a name' and "Enter age for") #asks user to enter name and age
#age = input('Enter age for') #not sure if I need this so I commented for now
def CollectNamesAges():
    count =0 #initialize at 0
    while(name !='END'): #while loop repeats until user enters END
        emptydic= emptydic + (sum(numbers)/ max(len(numbers))
    return emptydic
print("You have enterd N names of people, whose average age is A:")
#where N is an integer and A is a floating point number with only two decimals
#showing after the point. the string 'END' must not be placed in the dict.
#and must not be counted towards the number N
```

Comment: You don't use count,  you never call `CollectNameAges`, you can't add an int to a dict, and you call `while` on a variable that never changes. Please look at a beginning python tutorial and get a handle on what dicts, while, methods and variables are all about and update your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll need to figure out how you want to structure your dictionary.
2. You'll need a way to enter more than one names; otherwise, there's only going to be ONE name in your dictionary.

I've structured my code to have the name as key and the age as value.  I allow user to enter more than one name simply by asking if they want to add more and use a while loop to check against that.  You'll need to implement a check to see whether the user has enter an age.

```
>>> def collect_names ():
...     info = {}
...     total_age = 0
...     answer = 'y'
...     while answer == 'y':
...         name = input('Enter a name: ')
...         info [name] = int (input('Enter an age: '))
...         answer = input ('Enter more names? ').lower ()
...     for name in info:
...         total_age += info [name]
...     person_count = len (info)
...     avg_age = total_age / float (person_count)
...     return person_count, avg_age

>>> count, avg = collect_names()
Enter a name: John Doe
Enter an age: 21
Enter more names? y
Enter a name: Jane Doe
Enter an age: 29
Enter more names? y
Enter a name:James Smith
Enter an age: 25
Enter more names? n
>>>
```

**Output**

```
>>> print ("You've entered %d names whose average age is: %.2f" % (count, avg))
You've entered 3 names whose average age is: 25.00
```

Comment: I want to say thank you for actually replying to my question. I am new to this site and bcos of that had  to learn the hard way regarding how to ask question. anyways I truly love python this is my first time ever being exposed to programming its awesome I am drawn to it .

Comment: No problem. I understand as I too was in your shoe.  Feel free to click "answered" if you're satisfy with it. =)

Comment: i don't see where it says answered ha

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.  Thanks!